Error: undefined method 'start_with?' for nil:NilClass" when calling request_jwt_user_token in DocuSign Ruby gem
I'm encountering an error when attempting to call the request_jwt_user_token method in the DocuSign Ruby gem. The error message I'm receiving is:
undefined method 'start_with?' for nil:NilClass

Here's the relevant code snippet where the error occurs:
api_client.request_jwt_user_token(@integration_key, @user_id, private_key_filename, expires_in_seconds, scopes.join(" "))

Issue Details:

I'm using the DocuSign Ruby gem to integrate with the DocuSign API.
The request_jwt_user_token method is supposed to obtain a JWT user token, but it's throwing an   error.
All parameters passed to the method seem to be properly initialized and formatted.
The error occurs within the gem's internal implementation, so I'm not sure how to troubleshoot further.

Additional Information:
Ruby version: 2.7.5,
DocuSign Ruby gem version: 3.26.0, Operating system: ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS(virtual env on windows 11)
Double-check the parameter values passed to the method. Reviewing the gem's documentation and source code. Searching for similar issues online, but haven't found a solution yet.
I'd appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot or resolve this issue. If anyone has encountered a similar problem or has experience with the DocuSign Ruby gem, your assistance would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Can you try version 3.27.0.rc1 of the Docusign Ruby gem and let me know if it makes any difference?

Thanks, Inbar Gazit, you saved me!
The error was resolved after updating the Docusign Ruby Gem version to 3.27.0.rc1.

ok, I'll write an official answer here to explain this

There was an issue with the 3.26.0 version of the DocuSign.eSign Ruby gem. The issue had to do with a dependent package and was resolved in a later version. By using a newer version of the package you can avoid this error.
